# How to pass model to Register View in asp-core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm setting up register page which contains dropdown besides username and password. I want to pass dropdown values in model. In asp-core <2.1 I would just do this:

```
public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
{
    RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel(blabla)
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```

but now that Identity is embeded I can't find this method so I have no idea how to pass model to view so I could populate my dropdown. I managed to scaffold register page into my project but I only see "OnPostAsync" method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a property in RegisterModel that contains the list of items to bind the dropdown list. You must also add another property that sets the selection value when post occurs.

If you cannot change the RegisterModel class, create a new class that inherits the RegisterModel and add these 2 properties.

See the sample:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        modelView = new modelView();
        modelView.listItems = new listItems{"1", "2", "3"};

        return View(modelView);
    }
```

Comment: I did all that but I get null exception because Register model is not passed to the view and I have no idea where should I do that.

Comment: Did you set the model in top of the view? Like this: @model Model.modelView
Can you post the view code here?

Comment: Ohhh my bad, I added properties to "InputModel" which is null until submision and not RegisterModel. Now that I added to Register model it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! If possible, mark this answer as accepted. It will help the next developers to identify that was solved.